# Is it okay to send a letter of intent to attend a grad school, but withdraw if a scholarship is not provided?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Is it okay for a potential student to send a letter of intent to attend a university's grad school program, but withdraw if it becomes clear that a scholarship is not available. What are there any repercussions to this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a letter of intent? Did you send an informal acceptance by email stating that you are very interested in the program? Or do you send a formal acceptance letter stating that "Yes, I will be joining your university"?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that this should be a problem. Even if you get accepted for admission, and they send an official offer letter. You can always accept or decline it. If you choose to decline it, that is totally fine.

Comment: Let me add that accepting a scholarship and later declining it in favor of a scholarship from another university is the type of behavior that is frowned upon; however, it rarely results in any serious action taken by the institution granting the original offer.